# Index a NumPy array row-wise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, indexing

Say I have a NumPy array:

```
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
>>> X
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

and an array of indexes that I want to select for each row:

```
>>> ixs = np.array([[1, 3], [0, 1], [1, 2]])
>>> ixs
array([[1, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

How do I index the array X so that for every row in `X` I select the two indices specified in `ixs`?

So for this case, I want to select element 1 and 3 for the first row, element 0 and 1 for the second row, and so on. The output should be:

```
array([[2, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [10, 11]])
```

A slow solution would be something like this:

`output = np.array([row[ix] for row, ix in zip(X, ixs)])`

however this can get kinda slow for extremely long arrays. Is there a faster way to do this without a loop using NumPy?

**EDIT:** Some very approximate speed tests on a 2.5K * 1M array with 2K wide ixs (10GB):

`np.array([row[ix] for row, ix in zip(X, ixs)])` 0.16s

`X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T` 0.175s

`X.take(idx+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None])` 33s

`np.fromiter((X[i, j] for i, row in enumerate(ixs) for j in row), dtype=X.dtype).reshape(ixs.shape)` 2.4s

Comment: This produces an array that is close to what you want: `X[:,ixs]`.  Can anyone build on this?

Comment: do you count parallelization as an acceptable solution?

Comment: Can you reconstruct ixs like this instead: `ixs2 = np.array(((0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 0), ...))`? If so, then `X[ixs2[:,0], ixs2[:,1]]` will get what you need I think.

Comment: No @MohsinBukhari I am already parallelising on a higher loop. I also don't think parallelisation will help here as passing around info between processes is slow.

Comment: Hm, have you tried a straight-forward for-loop implementation with `numba` JIT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T
```

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) is the reference for complex indexing.

Comment: This is a neater solution but actually a bit slower in my (approximate) testing. I measured 1.75s vs 1.15s for the original version

Comment: @mxbi how big of an array are you testing this on? Unless you are using large arrays, I would expect list-comprehensions to be faster for these small sizes...

Comment: My array is 10K * 1M @juanpa.arrivillaga - although my initial test was on a much smaller array. On the large array this version is only very slightly slower than the list comprehension.

Comment: @mxbi mmm if I had to guess the double-transpose is just taking too long to make up for the efficient indexing... can you try timing my `.take` approach, maybe add the results as an edit to the question?

Comment: @mxbi 10K * 1M is too much memory(10G `long` ???), maybe you need to try 10K * 10K level.

Comment: @mxbi Theoretically this one will exploit numpy's performance, it should be faster than Python loop.

Comment: That's what I would expect @liliscent but they seem to be pretty neck and neck. Also apologies, the matrix was 2.5K * 1M, and yes it is 10GB in memory.

Comment: @mxbi How did you measure the performance ? You need to be sure the time is indeed consumed in this step, not like matrix loading or something irrelevant.

Comment: @liliscent why is it too much memory? 10GB is pretty small by modern standards... Although I do agree putting the timing code would be good for reproducibility

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, OP said `10K * 1M` matrix. If this was true, the memory is 80G ( 10G `long`, `long` is 8 `byte`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Turned out to be OP's typo.

Comment: @liliscent turns out, 80GB would still be small enough to fit into memory.

Comment: @liliscent I am just calling time.time() before and after a `for i in range(10): solution_line` and subtracting the timestamps. Everything's already in memory.

Comment: @mxbi Already computed in memory, or loaded from a file ? If the latter, your measuring has problem, because OS uses on-demand paging.

Comment: @liliscent The arrays `X` and `idx` are completely in memory (I just computed them and I'm in interactive python). I am only measuring the speed of `X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T` with nothing else.

Comment: @mxbi This sounds really strange to me. But I don't have a machine at hand to measure. If you are interested in, maybe you could write a C++ program to do the same thing (should be just a few lines), and look at the elapsed time.

Comment: @liliscent I would try `numba` before C

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Both are just a few lines, for measuring purpose. I'm curious why this approach will as slow as a Python loop.

Comment: @ liliscent @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you both for all the help, but I think these solutions are fast enough already. I was mainly wondering if there was a "numpy-onic" way of doing this without loops. I will accept this answer as I think it's neatest and is fast. However if you want me to test out another solution in the next few hours I can.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use `.take` thusly:

```
In [185]: X
Out[185]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [186]: idx
Out[186]:
array([[1, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 2]])

In [187]: X.take(idx + (np.arange(X.shape[0]) * X.shape[1]).reshape(-1, 1))
Out[187]:
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [10, 11]])
```

If your array dimensions are massive, it might be faster, albeit uglier, to do:

```
idx+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None]
```

Just for fun, see how the following performs:

```
np.fromiter((X[i, j] for i, row in enumerate(ixs) for j in row), dtype=X.dtype, count=ixs.size).reshape(ixs.shape)
```

#### Edit to add timings

```
In [15]: X = np.arange(1000*10000, dtype=np.int32).reshape(1000,-1)

In [16]: ixs = np.random.randint(0, 10000, (1000, 2))

In [17]: ixs.sort(axis=1)

In [18]: ixs
Out[18]:
array([[2738, 3511],
       [3600, 7414],
       [7426, 9851],
       ...,
       [1654, 8252],
       [2194, 8200],
       [5497, 8900]])

In [19]: %timeit  np.array([row[ix] for row, ix in zip(X, ixs)])
928 µs ± 23.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T
23.6 µs ± 491 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit X.take(idx+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None])
20.6 µs ± 530 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit np.fromiter((X[i, j] for i, row in enumerate(ixs) for j in row), dtype=X.dtype, count=ixs.size).reshape(ixs.shape)
1.42 ms ± 9.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@mxbi I've added some timings and my results aren't really consistent with yours, you should check it out

Here's a larger array:

```
In [33]: X = np.arange(10000*100000, dtype=np.int32).reshape(10000,-1)

In [34]: ixs = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (10000, 2))

In [35]: ixs.sort(axis=1)

In [36]: X.shape
Out[36]: (10000, 100000)

In [37]: ixs.shape
Out[37]: (10000, 2)
```

With some results:

```
In [42]: %timeit  np.array([row[ix] for row, ix in zip(X, ixs)])
11.4 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T
596 µs ± 17.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [44]: %timeit X.take(ixs+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None])
540 µs ± 16.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Now, we are using column 500 indices instead of two, and we see the list-comprehension start winning out:

```
In [45]: ixs = np.random.randint(0, 100000, (10000, 500))

In [46]: ixs.sort(axis=1)

In [47]: %timeit  np.array([row[ix] for row, ix in zip(X, ixs)])
93 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [48]: %timeit X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T
133 ms ± 638 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [49]: %timeit X.take(ixs+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None])
87.5 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This one unfortunately seems kinda slow. On a 10K x 1M matrix, the faster version takes 33 seconds to complete, versus 170ms for the list comprehension.

Comment: @mxbi yeaaah if your dimensions are massive, the there's a lot of overhead to the `idx + ...` stuff, although, try with `idx+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None]` I wonder if it is faster... even if not fast enough.

Comment: @mxbi 10G `long` is indeed too much, the bottleneck is perhaps OS paging.

Comment: @liliscent This machine has 128GB ram and no swap so I am not paging. Yeah @ juanpa I guess this works better on smaller arrays.

Comment: @mxbi did you try this version: `idx+np.arange(0, X.shape[0]*X.shape[1], X.shape[1])[:,None]`, I don't think it will be fast enough, but I'm curious if it is faster than the other...

Comment: @mxbi check out an approach with `np.fromiter`, see how it compares...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 2.4 seconds

Comment: @mxbi does adding the `count` argument to `fromiter` make an appreciable difference?

Comment: Not outside margin of error. Seems about the same

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for doing these timings, the results are very interesting (and will probably help others in the future). In mine, my matrix was of width 1M and I was taking 2K indices. This probably explains it.

Answer (score 1):

The usual suggestion for indexing items from rows is:

```
X[np.arange(X.shape[0])[:,None], ixs]
```

That is, make a row index of shape (n,1) (column vector), which will broadcast with the (n,m) shape of `ixs` to give a (n,m) solution.

This basically the same as:

```
X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T
```

which broadcasts a (n,) index against a (m,n), and transposes.

Timings are essentially the same:

```
In [299]: X = np.ones((1000,2000))
In [300]: ixs = np.random.randint(0,2000,(1000,200))
In [301]: timeit X[np.arange(len(ixs)), ixs.T].T
6.58 ms ± 71.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [302]: timeit X[np.arange(X.shape[0])[:,None], ixs]
6.57 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

and for comparison:

```
In [307]: timeit np.array([row[ix] for row, ix in zip(X, ixs)])
6.63 ms ± 229 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I'm a little surprised that this list comprehension does so well.  I wonder how the relative advantages compare when the dimensions change, particularly in the relative shape of `X` and `ixs` (long, wide etc).

---

The first solution is the style of indexing produced by `ix_`:

```
In [303]: np.ix_(np.arange(3), np.arange(2))
Out[303]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
[X[i][[y]] for i, y in enumerate(ixs)]
```

EDIT: I just noticed you wanted no loop solution.

Comment: This one is also pretty neck and neck with my original solution (if I wrap it in a call to np.array)